# Parse.com Access objects with 'includeKey'

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Good Day,

I use includeKey to fetch pointer objects, but I can use them... Here is my code:

```
    var diagQuery = PFQuery(className: "CaseDiagnosis")
    diagQuery.whereKey("patientcase",matchesQuery: caseQuery)
    diagQuery.includeKey("patientcase")        
    var remoteDiags = diagQuery.findObjects()
     println(remoteDiags)
```

console output:

```
[<CaseDiagnosis:IvQyy1i1ic:(null)> {
  diagcode = "Z01.1";
  firstcontact = "<FirstContact:7L3HB9Vnp2>";
  patientcase = "<PatientCase:T2A4t37Iaw>";
}]
```

How do I access 'patientcase'?

My code so far:

```
for diag : PFObject! in remoteCases as [PFObject]{
        // This does not require a network access.
        var p = diag["patientcase"] as PFObject  <----------Error
        println("retrieved related post: \(p)")
    }
```

I get an error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of the error, it might be complaining that one of the values in the `remoteCases` array is `nil`, try logging `diag` inside the loop.

Also be aware that if the `PatientCase` the pointer is pointing to has been deleted, you'll have issues also. The pointer will have the ID but the full object will be `nil`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try logging inside the loop and give feedback.